# Range of $|\vec a - \vec b|^2+|\vec b - \vec c|^2+|\vec c - \vec a|^2$

Tags: inequality, optimization, vectors, inner-products, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

In $\mathbf R^3$, let $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ be three vectors such that $|\vec a|=2$, $|\vec b|=3$ and $|\vec c|=4$. Then find the minimum and maximum possible value of the expression

$$|\vec a - \vec b|^2+|\vec b - \vec c|^2+|\vec c - \vec a|^2$$

I have tried the following:

`|a-b|^2 + |b-c|^2 + |c-a|^2
= 2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) -2(a.b + b.c + c.a)
= 58 - 2(a.b + b.c + c.a)`

Now,
`(a+b+c)^2 >= 0
=> a^2 + b^2 + c^2 >= -2(a.b + b.c + c.a)
=> -2(a.b + b.c + c.a) <= 29
=> |a-b|^2 + |b-c|^2 + |c-a|^2 <= 87`

But I can't find the maximum value.

Comment: @Mattos I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\measuredangle(\vec{c},\vec{b})=\alpha$, $\measuredangle(\vec{a},\vec{c})=\beta$ and $\measuredangle(\vec{a},\vec{b})=\gamma$. Thus,
$$|\vec a - \vec b|^2+|\vec b - \vec c|^2+|\vec c - \vec a|^2=58-24\cos\alpha-16\cos\beta-12\cos\gamma,$$
which gives the minimum easily: 
$$58-24-16-12=6.$$

The maximum is $87$ because
$$\sum_{cyc}(\vec{a}-\vec{b})^2=3(\vec{a}^2+\vec{b}^2+\vec{c}^2)-(\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})^2\leq3(\vec{a}^2+\vec{b}^2+\vec{c}^2)=87$$

Comment: What are $\alpha\beta\gamma$?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel I fixed my post. See now.

Comment: But what's the maximum then?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel The maximum is $87$ because $\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\vec{a}-\vec{b}\right)^2=3(\vec{a}^2+\vec{b}^2+\vec{c}^2)-(\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})^2\leq3(\vec{a}^2+\vec{b}^2+\vec{c}^2)=87$.